# How can Upgrade sqlite database to next version with saving user data

Tags: android, sqlite

i have an application with version 1.0 and now i hade made newxt version and now i want ot upgrade the database but i can not upgrade the database. the android studio give error from this line:

```
 db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

.
here is full code:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor SignalRes = db.rawQuery("select * from signal", null);

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS signal");
    onCreate(db);

    SignalRes.moveToFirst();
    while (!SignalRes.isAfterLast()) {
        insertSignal((SignalRes.getInt(0)), SignalRes.getString(1), SignalRes.getString(2)
                , SignalRes.getString(3), SignalRes.getString(4), SignalRes.getString(5)
                , SignalRes.getString(6), SignalRes.getString(7), SignalRes.getString(8));
        SignalRes.moveToNext();
    }
    SignalRes.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

onUpgrade already has a db variable passed in, so you should just use that variable rather than assigning to it again. It will be better if you can post the error message as well, but I'm suspecting you are opening the database recursively.

By the way, check this [post](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade) out, you also need to clarify the relation between newVersion and oldVersion to indicate when you want the database to be updated.

So your code should look something like this:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < YOUR_NEW_DB_VERSION) {
         db.execSQL(YOUR_QUERY_TO_MOVE_DATA_FROM_TABLE1_TO_TABLE2);
         db.execSQL(YOUR_QUERY_TO_DROP_TABLE1);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes. you are right. but if i dont write db=this.getReadableDatabase(); it bring for me a null table because it is not open for reading from it. @charles-li

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted, if you still have problems let me know then. And can you clarify how you are trying to update your database? ex. Insert data into another table?

Comment: yes. first i put the table's data to a cursor and then remove it. then i create it again. after creating the table i will write data to the new table. but i want to know why this line have error?@charles-li

Comment: first of all, you're trying to edit the database, so you should call getWritableDatabase() (not in onUpgrade). And if you check the documentation, it says "The first time this is called, the database will be opened and onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and/or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called." So you are in essence making it loop recursively since you are calling the function in onUpgrade.

Comment: check my updated post, that might give you a better idea what you should do.

Comment: my way was not good to insert data in my new table? @charles-li

Comment: Now i got this in my logCat: No adapter attached; skipping layout@charles-li

Comment: and the adapter is a different error/problem. Remember to set the adapter after you create it.

Answer (score -1):

1) Define a variable like that **private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;**

2) Your SQLiteOpenHelper Class Constructor and **super** method will check version

```
public EzberletDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context=context;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.close();
    try {
        context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
    } catch (Exception e) {

        context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    }
}
```

3) onUpgrade method if version chanced that method will execute

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try {
        String query="";
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS signal";
        db.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(db);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Message.message(context,""+e);
    }
}
```

**Finally:** if you increase DATABASE_VERSION to 6, your db will be updated. I hope you can't lose user datas with this way.

Comment: what did you mean by writing this code:  context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);  @hayrullah-cansu

Comment: It's not relevant your problem. But that code try open database or else create a database. @moji

Comment: I tried the code: context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE, null); but i got this error: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode @hayrullah-cansu

Comment: Can you post your extended SQLiteOpenHelper class and usage it? @moji